# PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant self - assumed 'self'

Tags: php

I inherited some php 5.x code that complains on php 7.4.3 with this warning:

```
PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant self - assumed 'self' 
(this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

The offending line is here:

```
class Array_sort
{
 static private $key;
 static private $type = 'ASC';
 
 public static function sort_by_key($array, $key, $type = 'ASC') {
  self::$key = $key;
  self::$type = $type;
  usort($array, array(self,'sort_by')); //<-- offending use of 'self'
  return $array;
 }
 
 private static function sort_by($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b)
        return 0;
    // other comparisons omitted but result in 1 or -1 being returned
 }
}
```

I'm not sure what self is trying to refer to in the call to usort.

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: `usort($array, array('Array_sort', 'sort_by'))`

Answer (score 3):

Use `self` to refer to the current class. Not class name.

Try using magic constants:
`if(isset($user->$name) || property_exists(__CLASS__, $name)){`

From php manual: `__CLASS__`

The class name. (Added in PHP 4.3.0) As of PHP 5 this constant returns the class name as it was declared (case-sensitive). In PHP 4 its value is always lowercased. The class name includes the namespace it was declared in (e.g. Foo\Bar). Note that as of PHP 5.4 CLASS works also in traits. When used in a trait method, CLASS is the name of the class the trait is used in.

Read more: 
https://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Solution:

```
usort($array, array(__CLASS__,'sort_by'));
```